# Using Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 16.10, I have had a bizare recurring problem where the system crashes after login

Tags: ubuntu, login

f I try to login using the normal graphical interface, by desktop environment  (Unity) doesn't load, the cursor is frozen in place, and the computer will not accept any input. If I launch the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and login that way, I will get a series of error messages in a dump stack, and then lose ability to offer input to the system. I don't know what most of these messages mean, any help would be appreciated!

The part that really confuses me is that this has happened across multiple fresh installs after varied amounts of time

```
System:
CPU: AMD Athlon x4 760k
GPU: MSI R7 260X
SSD (boot): Crucial MX100
HDD (backup/mass storage): Seagate 2TB enterprise 
Power Supply: Antec 450 Watt
RAM: 8GB G skill Ripjaws @1866 Mhz
```

[image]

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBpQv.jpg) are the rest of the error messages.

Comment: Is there any chance you can get the `Call Trace:` output that happens just above this portion of the output.